# Laravel belongs to many with additional methods

Tags: php, laravel

For followers relation on same User model I used `belongsToMany()`

```
public function followers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'follow_id', 'user_id');
}
```

But since I am using this for chat list on load with vue I am on page load passing `json_encode(auth()->user()->followers)` which works as I needed.

But when I am lets say using only some columns like:

`->select(['id', 'name', 'avatar']);`

I have additional method for `avatar`:

```
public function image() {
    return $this->avatar || 'some-default-image';
}
```

How can I pass that as well for each of many? Without `withDefault` method..

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `Accessor` function:

> [Laravel Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Basically you define an accessor function in your model:

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
{
    return $value || 'some-default-image';
}
```

Then when you access the `avatar` property using `->avatar`, the `accessor` function will get called and you will get the computed value.

====================================================================

The comment has words limit.

You have followers table where each follower is a `User`. You use relationship to filter all followers which are a group of `User`s. You wanted `getInfo()` to be called on each follower so that the additional data is appended to your `JSON` structure.

In that case, you don't need to filter through each follower and call `getInfo()` yourself. You use `accessor` method, put your code in `getInfo()` into an `accessor` method, and modify `$appends` array in your `User` model, then then `JSON` data will be automatically appended.

```
public function getUserInfoAttribute()
{
    $userInfo = ... //use logic in your original getInfo method
    return $userInfo;
}
```

Then you add `user_info` into your `User` model's `$appends` array:

```
protected $appends = ['user_info'];
```

This way, your `user_info` will be automatically included when your instance is serialized into `JSON`.

Like I said in the comment, you should check out:

> [Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

for more information.

As to `API`s , whether you are using `Vue` or `React` or anything, when passing `JSON` data for your frontend code to consume, you are basically creating `api`s. FYI:

> [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources)

Comment: what if something is not a direct column value? Like in case I have method on user model `getInfo() {//checkUserType and get different relations data}`

Comment: @StupidKid In that case you should just call `getInfo()` method on your user instance.

Comment: Well I can't  cuz I am passing relation as json to vue front so the connections are not passed as well. I can make entirely new method where I get all followers and do what every I need but I thought there is a simpler and better option.

Comment: @StupidKid Generally speaking, when you are creating APIs, you should pass carefully designed JSON structures so that your frontend code won't have complex logic dealing with compound data. In your case, you have two ways to do that. First you can check out this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json. You can append additional attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your database. Also `Laravel` provides convenient ways to generate API resources. Check out official docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#introduction.

Comment: I am not creating an api for this part of the code.... I can't find whee you seen that I said that.... I just need to get followers which I do and some specific data from those followers from their relations since not all users have same types. Since you dont understand that I will just make another method, filter through it and return an json or what ever I need. I though there may be an option to pass relation methods within previous relation that is called.

Comment: @StupidKid I don't think you understand my answer. You have followers table where each follower is a `User`. You use relationship to filter all followers which are a group of users. You wanted `getInfo()` to be called on each follower so that the additional data is appended to your JSON structure. In that case, you don't need to filter through each follower and call `getInfo()` yourself. You use `accessor` method, put your code in `getInfo()` into an `accessor` method, and modify `$appends` in your User model, then then JSON data will be automatically appended.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your `User` model

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['image'];

    // other stuff..
}
```

this will forcefully inject your computed property ie. image in every `User` model instance but for it work you have to name your method (or create another) like `getImageAttribute()`and not simply `image()`

```
// getter for `image` property in user model object
public function getImageAttribute() { 
    return $this->avatar || 'some-default-image';
}
```